# Raid 10 Failure, Non Bootable

Tags: hard-drive, raid

One drive failed , after 8 years of this server running.

The raid should had backed up but it failed.

Any idea why:[image]

Note the part where it says “Offline Member” is now green and says “Member Disk” but still fails!

Comment: You could be an unlucky fellow, and the disk encountered a URE while it was rebuilding.

Comment: anyway to know? what shouid i do?